# Highlight word on double click and copy to clipboard

Tags: key-bindings, highlight, os-clipboard

I am using this [excellent solution by Peter Rinker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876850/how-to-highlight-all-occurrences-of-a-word-in-vim-on-double-clicking) to highlight all occurrences of a word on double clicking.

```
nnoremap <silent> <2-LeftMouse> :let @/='\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>'<cr>:set hls<cr>
```

Is there a way to modify this to  also copy this word into the clipboard, i.e. the `"+` register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of that solution is

```
:let @/='\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>'<cr>
```

The `expand('<cword>')` part will grab the text under the cursor, and the `escape` function will make sure that it's literal text rather than a regex. However, we don't want to modify the text we copy, so we can just call the `expand('<cword>')` part. So you want to add

```
:let @+=expand('<cword>')<cr>
```

to some part of the mapping. Since the order on those three ex calls don't really matter, you can put it wherever you'd like. One solution (adding it to the end) would give:

```
nnoremap <silent> <2-LeftMouse> :let @/='\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>'<cr>:set hls<cr>:let @+=expand('<cword>')<cr>
```